# preventDefault to stop refresh on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I have below line of code which simply places a link on the parent page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="createNewsLink" class="short" onclick="javascript:func1(); func2(param1,param2,param3);return false;"><caps:msg textId="createNews"/></a>
```

`Onclick` of the above link 2 functions are getting called:

###func1():

```
var timestamp;

function func1() {
    timestamp = +new Date();
    return false;
}
```

###func2():

```
function  func2(param1,param2,param3,param4){ 
    var win;
    var location = window.location.href; // location A
    var encodeStringVar = encodeString(param3);
    win = window.open(param1+'/struts1.action?param2='+param2+'&param3='+ escape(encodeStringVar) +'#'+param4,target='t1','toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,width=990,height=630, top=100, left=100');
    window.location.href = location; // location A
    return win;
}
```

On click of link on parent page, a popup opens by calling struts action, and it works just fine. Only problem is when the link on parent page is clicked, it refreshes the parent page. I don't want it to refresh and I tried adding `return false` in the link and Javascript `void()` function, Also I tried by adding an event listener for click event on this link as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#createNewsLink").click(function(event) {
        //return false;
        event.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

> and below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("createNewsLink").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

But none of these did the trick, can someone please point out the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Could you consider to try :

```js
(function(){
  var linkElement = document.querySelector('#createNewsLink');
  linkElement.addEventListener('click',function(e) {

    var param1 = e.target.getAttribute('attr-param1');
    var param2 = e.target.getAttribute('attr-param2');
    console.log(param1,param2);
    // Do what ever you want here.
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})();
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" id="createNewsLink" class="short" attr-param1="foo" attr-param2="bar">Click me</a>
```

Here i avoid any Event binding from html, and centralize all traitment / binding in one place. Then i point one way to find back mandatory params for your traitment.